# Programatically changing PDF quality in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

Can I programatically change the quality of a PDF?

I have a client that is a newspaper, and when they submit the PDF form of the paper to their site they are submitting the same copy they send to the printer which can range from 30-50Mb. I can manually lower the quality (still plenty high for the web) and it will be 3-5Mb so this will help my hosting substantially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like something that would require nothing short of the Adobe PDF SDK / libraries.  I have worked with them quite bit, but I have never attempted to change the resolution of an existing PDF.  The libraries are pricey so it's likely that is not an option for you.

I want to say that Perl's PDF::API2 has an optimize script bundled with it, but I have never used that functionality.  It may be worth a look.  The module itself is pretty thorough.  Although, a PDF that large not be that fastest to process with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [TCPDF](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf) library or [php documentation](http://ar.php.net/pdf).
I never worked with pdfs in php, but I think you can do that you need with TCPDF easily. If your pdf is composed by images, check [this example](http://www.tecnick.com/pagefiles/tcpdf/example_009.phps), maybe help you.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

[Zend_Pdf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html) is the best Free library for reading and manipulating existing PDFs, but it does not go nearly deep enough to do what you need.  I do not believe there is a PHP library for manipulating PDF files at that level (that is, being able to extract embedded images and replace them with lower quality versions).